# On Windows, where docker is running on oracle virtualBox, is there an option to persist data of mongodb using volume?

Tags: mongodb, docker

On Windows, where docker is running on oracle virtualBox, is there an option to persist data of mongodb using volume?

I read on official documentation of docker hub that its not possible.

for MySQL, its possible and I am able to use its default implementation (where I cannot trace the volume, still its ok)

Answer (score 0):

Of course it's possible.

I'm assuming you're using Docker Toolbox. If so then directory `C:\Users` is mounted inside the boo2docker VM as `/c/Users`. Per MongoDB documentation that means the command below won't work:

```
docker run --name some-mongo -v /c/Users/your_user_name/MongoDB_Data:/data/db -d mongo
```

However, there is nothing stopping you from mounting a directory that exists solely inside the VM, like this:

```
docker run --name some-mongo -v /src/mongodb/data:/data/db -d mongo
```

Furthermore, MongoDB Docker image documentation says nothing about named volumes, so the following should also work:

```
docker volume create mongodb_data
docker run --name some-mongo -v mongodb_data:/data/db -d mongo
```

Comment: WARNING (Windows & OS X): The default Docker setup on Windows and OS X uses a VirtualBox VM to host the Docker daemon. Unfortunately, the mechanism VirtualBox uses to share folders between the host system and the Docker container is not compatible with the memory mapped files used by MongoDB (see vbox bug, docs.mongodb.org and related jira.mongodb.org bug). This means that it is not possible to run a MongoDB container with the data directory mapped to the host.

Comment: https://hub.docker.com/_/mongo. The above comment in this link confused me. I will give it  a whirl and see how it goes

Comment: There is nothing confusing about it. As I s to as stated in my answer you cannot mount Windows folder as a volume, but there should be no problem with Linux folder from inside the VM or a named volume.

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, If I am mounting linux folder, will the data be persisted after restart? That is basically my original question is.

Comment: It should be. Also restart of what? Container, VM or Windows host?

Comment: Is there a difference?

Comment: Container restart may persist, I think, since VM is there.

Comment: But, when VM or windows got restarted, how data will persist?

Comment: Even if you do not use any volumes in most cases the data will persist when you restart the container, the VM or the Windows host. The purpose of volumes is to persist data when the container is destroyed and recreated, for example during an update.